# How to see if a plugin is already installed with Perl

Tags: perl, plugins

I have a Perl script that requires a couple of plugins, for istance nmap. How can I see if the plugins are already installed and, in case they are not, install them? I tryed with the following code but it doesn't work very well, what I am trying to do is capture the "bash: nmap: command not found" output. I tryed with both stdout and stderr.

```
print "Checking nmap...\n";

my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
    system("nmap");
};

if ($stdout=~m/command not found/) {
    print "nmap not found, installing...\n";
    system("rpm -i nmap-4.75-1.26.x86_64.rpm");
}

else {
    print "nmap is already installed.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
my $cmd='which nmap';
my $output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
my $exit_value=$? >> 8;
if ($exit_value){
  print "not found $cmd, error: $output\n";
}else{
  print "Found $cmd at $output\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the third line please? I don't like to use code that I don't understand :D

Comment: This is the usually cruddy error checking for `system`. I would simply use [File::Which](http://p3rl.org/File::Which) instead, or if `system` cannot be avoided, at least [leave the error checking to IPC::System::Simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478060).

Comment: $? contains the exit value of the command. The command executed in a shell so $? lower 128 bit contain the shell errors, upper 128 contain the actual script error.

Comment: the >> 8 shift binary, keep the upper part so the cmd exit value. Without this, if a cmd exit with 1 you will see 129 in $?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I see if the plugins are already installed and, in case they are not, install them?

[This is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7664829#comment-9314571), do not check for dependencies at run time. Instead you **declare** the dependencies in your distro meta file and check for them at build time and perhaps abort the build. The easiest way to do so is with [`requires_external_bin` from `Module::Install`](http://p3rl.org/Module::Install). This integrates nicely into the existing RPM infrastructure. - In other words, learn the basics of packaging and which problems this solves.

If you cannot rely on the user having permission to install it system-wide, create an [Alien](http://p3rl.org/Alien) distro that downloads the source and installs it into the share tree. But once you go down that rabbit hole, be aware that it's deep - you would also need to take care of the [deps of nmap itself](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=nmap.spec&package=nmap&project=network%3Autilities) somehow.

Comment: The purpose of all this is to create an installer for my Perl suite actually. Before installing additional plugins this "setup" installs Perl dependencies for instance.

Comment: [Module::Install](http://p3rl.org/Module::Install) (or [Module::Build](http://p3rl.org/Module::Build) or [MakeMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils::MakeMaker)) is that installer. Why would you invent your own?

Comment: I am reading Module::Install documentation actually but my question is does this module require installation or is it a core one? My setup needs to run on machines that may not have anything.

Comment: Module::Install is not a core module. It does not require prior installation on the target machine because a copy is bundled in the `inc` directory of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Like daxim pointed out [requires_external_bin](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aInstall%3a%3aExternal#requires_external_bin) from `Module::Install::External` is a good way to ensure that your binary is installed.

If you can't use Module::Install in your application you might try searching the PATH environment variable like this:

```perl
use File::Spec;

$\="\n";
print installed($_) ? "$_ installed" : "$_ not installed" for qw/nmap ls cat nosuchfile less/;

sub installed {
    my $name = shift;

    foreach my $path (File::Spec->path()) {
        my $bin = File::Spec->catfile($path, $name);
        return $bin if -e -f -x $bin;
    }
}
```

This should output something like this:

```
$ perl test.pl
nmap installed
ls installed
cat installed
nosuchfile not installed
less installed
```

The downside of this is of course, that the binary you are looking for has to reside in $PATH.

Comment: A thoroughly debugged, portable incarnation of the path searching code above is available as [File::Which](http://p3rl.org/File::Which) from CPAN.